# Silverlight Path is blurry - How to snap to pixels?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a `Canvas` onto which I draw a `Path`:

```
<Path Data="M 380 110 v -10 l 100 -100"
      Stroke="#C0C0C2" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
```

Even though the `StrokeThickness` is set to 1, the vertical part of the path is drawn across 2 pixels and in a lighter color.

[image: Silverlight Path]

I know that WPF has the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property that would fix it, and I read that in Silverlight there is a `UseLayoutRounding` property that you can use in some cases to have the same effect, however it does not seem to apply to `Path`.

Is there anything I can do to get that line drawn properly?

Answer (score 2):

There is a pixel snapper class over at MSDN on [Dave Relyea's Silverlight Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx). That is what I have used in the past for Silverlight pixel snapping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it did not work for me. The coordinates I seem to understand that this class works by snapping the bounds of an item to round pixels, but the coordinates I use are already integers, and in the case of a path, snapping the bounds might not mean that the contents fall on round pixels either.